# Why is there a lot of noise in the Wolfram Blockchain?

Tags: data, dataset, data-acquisition, cryptography

I tried to look into the transaction history of the Wolfram Blockchain. I tried this:-

```
translist = Flatten[BlockchainBlockData[#]["TransactionList"] & /@ Range[1010, 1020]];
BlockchainGet /@ translist
```

As you can see, between block 1010 and 1020, around 50% of the Blockchain are meaningful messages (e.g. images, number, formulae, graphs etc.), while the remaining 50% of them are the noises. When the block number increase, the percentage of meaningless messages increase. What are those noises and why would they appear?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Look like encoding issues? Like that's what one might get if the character encoding is wrong for what you expect it to be. Why that would be the case, I don't know.

Comment: Perhaps the data is encrypted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of those transactions contain expressions added to the Wolfram blockchain using BlockchainPut and you see that as noise. Be aware that blockchain functions are tagged as experimental and may change. V12 introduced new blockchain functionalities focused on Bitcoin and Ethereum. You can see use cases here:

https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/blockchain/?product=mathematica